# Entering Germany before granting of residence permit

Tags: germany, us-citizens

I am a US citizen, trying to move to Germany (Berlin). I have found a job in Berlin and with the company, am applying for a residence permit. Since I am a software developer with no negative history, I think it's fairly reasonable to assume that it will be granted.

However, I will be arriving in Berlin before that process completes and possibly, before the application is made. I will not start with the new job until authorized to do so, as I don't intend to work illegally. I have rented an apartment (through a reputable site online) for 6 months.

What do I tell the border officers to both be as honest as possible and not get denied entry? I do plan on doing tourist activities while I wait for the process to complete. I am concerned that they will look at my amount of luggage and desire for a longer stay without proof of visa application and deny me entry.

I do currently have a return flight for about 60 days after entry and significant financial resources.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a US citizen, you come under [§41 I AufenthV](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/aufenthv/__41.html). You can enter visa-free and then apply for a residence permit while in Germany. You have 90 days to make the application. So there is nothing to hide about what you are planning to do.

Comment: Thank you! That's a huge weight off my shoulders

Comment: Just be aware that you can do job interviews, but you cannot work yet.